# Stop UUID injection in MYSQL Database

Tags: authentication, web-application, vulnerability, mysql, uuid

I have a cordova app that logs users in based on their devices model+platform+uuid. For example:
Pixel 2Android39798721218.
The way this works when a user uses a new device is detailed in the following:

1. Users opens app
2. App sends uuid code to checking page like: login-uuid?id=(uuid_here)
3. If the uuid does not exist in the database the user is directed to a login page with the url: login?uuid=(uuid_here)
4. User logs in and the uuid is sent to the login backend where it gets stored in a database
5. When the user opens the app again they are logged in because their uuid is in the database

My question is basically, if someone knows a users login details. They can navigate to login?uuid=foo and then even if the user changes their password the attacker can still login by navigating to login-uuid?id=foo. Is there any way to mitigate this or will simply removing all logged in devices when a user resets there password be enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your suspiscion that an attacker would remain logged in is correct. Therefore, it is common practice to invalidate all active sessions for a user when the password is reset. With your setup, that would mean removing all UUIDs connected to a user when she changes her password.

Two other somewhat unrelated issues with your setup:

- 39798721218 is not an [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). (It might be a little on the short side to be a good session identifier.)
- Under no circumstances should you include the session identifier in the URL. That is unsafe as it will be exposed in browser history, server logs, and copy pasted URLs.
- There is nothing that prevents a client from faking the model and platform parts of the ID. (But if the token still is secret and has lots of entropy, that doesn't have to be a problem.)